# Listing files by particular expression from GCS in Java

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

Have anyone achieved this functionality before ? It's equivalent to `ls -ltr *xyz*` in unix and I would like to achieve the same in my cloud dataflow code.
Any lead would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this filtering on the client side. Here is an example using the [`google-cloud`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/) java client library to access the Google Cloud Storage APIs.

The example below lists all files in the root directory of the bucket which matches the given regular expression pattern.

I've used regular expressions instead of the glob pattern that shell commands like `ls` support since regular expressions are more flexible.

I would recommend you go through the [java library documentation for `google-cloud`](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.20.1/apidocs/index.html).

### Example

```java
    import com.google.api.gax.paging.Page;
    import com.google.cloud.storage.Blob;
    import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
    import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage.BlobListOption;
    import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    
    /**
     * An example which lists the files in the specified GCS bucket matching the
     * specified regular expression pattern.
     *
     * <p>Run it as PROGRAM_NAME <BUCKET_NAME> <REGEX_MATCH_PATTERN>
     */
    public class ListBlobsSample {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Instantiates a Storage client
        Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
    
        // The name of the GCS bucket
        String bucketName = args[0];
        // The regular expression for matching blobs in the GCS bucket.
        // Example: '.*abc.*'
        String matchExpr = args[1];
    
        List<String> results = listBlobs(storage, bucketName, Pattern.compile(matchExpr));
        System.out.println("Results: " + results.size() + " items.");
        for (String result : results) {
          System.out.println("Blob: " + result);
        }
      }
    
      // Lists all blobs in the bucket matching the expression.
      // Specify a regex here. Example: '.*abc.*'
      private static List<String> listBlobs(Storage storage, String bucketName, Pattern matchPattern)
          throws IOException {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    
        // Only list blobs in the current directory
        // (otherwise you also get results from the sub-directories).
        BlobListOption listOptions = BlobListOption.currentDirectory();
        Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list(bucketName, listOptions);
        for (Blob blob : blobs.iterateAll()) {
          if (!blob.isDirectory() && matchPattern.matcher(blob.getName()).matches()) {
            results.add(blob.getName());
          }
        }
        return results;
      }
    }
```

### Using just prefix matching

If you instead need to match just prefixes in the object names, [Objects: list API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list) supports it.

You need to specify the `prefix` query parameter in the request when doing `GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket/o`. This is also supported using the java client library (you will have to specify it while building the `BlobListOption` you pass to `storage.list()`).

> **prefix**
>
> string
>
> Filter results to objects whose names begin with this prefix.

### gsutil

`gsutil` supports such queries and it does the filtering solely on the client side (for some cases it issues multiple requests too).

Comment: @BalajeeVenkatesh - I've added a very basic but working example which uses regex pattern matching on the results and also added reference to the library's java documentation for further reference.

Comment: Thank you for your help but after putting a lot of efforts in place I haven't been able to get it working in my Eclipse. I guess these are issues with the jar versions I'm using to resolve the dependencies. Basically 'StorageOptions' and 'Page' classes are under red lines. Could you please share the versions of  'gax' and 'storage' related jars you used to make this code functional?

Comment: I would recommend looking into some form of dependency/package management tool like `maven` which lets you pull dependencies easily. The reason being you will have to download a whole set of jars to satisfy all the dependencies (i.e. dependencies of your dependencies and so on). If you use `maven` or any of the popular java dependency management tools, the lines you need to add to the config to pull in the dependencies is listed [here](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.20.1/dependency-info.html)

Comment: @BalajeeVenkatesh - The problem you're facing is quite different from your initial question and I would suggest asking a separate question if you're having issues with building a project and handling dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

GCS supports prefix queries, you can efficiently list xyz*; but to list *xyz* you would have to list the entire bucket and filter at the client.

Answer (score 0):

The following may not be exactly helpful for your use case, but if you are looking to narrow down the results by a certain prefix and then apply regex to match your final regex.

```
 Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
 Bucket bucket = storage.get(bucketName)
 BlobListOption blobListOption = Storage.BlobListOption.prefix(prefixPattern)
 for (Blob blob : bucket.list(blobListOption).iterateAll()) {
    System.out.println(blob);
 }
```